# SOAP url in browser

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

When you enter soap servers url in browser, normally it produces blank page. But if memory serves me I saw somewhere something like

> Hello, this is our soap service. For
>   documentation please follow this link.
>   To get an account, please follow this
>   link. Blahblah.

How can I do that? (Using PHP SoapServer, if that matters).

I did try to just print everything at the bottom of soap-server-handling php code but in that case soap server doesnt work when called from proper soap client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you saw doing that was probably checking for one or more things in the headers and acting upon what it saw.  For example, it could inspect

```
USER_AGENT
ACCEPT
ACCEPT_ENCODING
```

etc, etc, etc.

For you to do this in PHP, you will need your check to be run before your SoapServer gets the request.  You can access the header values by inspecting $*SERVER.   Most of them will start with HTTP*.  To get started just

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is look into WSDL (Web Service Description Language).  Languages like .NET produce them for you.